# Units in the camera frame of the matlab's calibration toolbox

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, camera-calibration

What is the units of the coordinates in camera frame by using matlab's camera calibration toolbox? Say I transform some points in pixels to camera's frame, what are the units? Is there some possible way of knowing?

I found this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022663/matlab-what-are-the-units-of-matlab-camera-calibration-toolbox), but no definite answer.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please clarify how exactly you are transforming those points?

The pin-hole camera model looks like this:

```
w*[x,y,1] = [X,Y,Z,1]*[R;t]*K
```

`[X,Y,Z]` are the world coordinates in world units (e. g. millimeters), and `[x,y]` are the image coordinates in pixels. `K` is the matrix of camera intrinsics, and `R` and `t` are the camera extrinsics. `w` is an arbitrary scale factor.

If you take a world point `[X,Y,Z,1]` and multiply it by `[R;t]`, then you get a point in a "camera's coordinate system", where the origin is at the focal point, and the units are the same as in your world coordinates (e. g. millimeters).

If you take a point in the image `[x,y,1]` and multiply it by the inverse of `K`, then you get a point in "normalized image coordinates", where the origin is at the optical center, and the axis have no units. This happens because you are dividing `x` and `y` in pixels by the focal length `fx` and `fy`, which is also in pixels. So pixels cancel out.